# How to avoid jquery ajax error message printing to console

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can I avoid the error being logged in the console when my ajax call fails?

I used the `.fail` method like this:

```
$.post('/foo/add', {body: data} )
      .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log('failed')
       })
       .done(function(response) {
            //..
       });
```

But I still get an error in the console:

> jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:8080/foo/add 403
>
> failed

What am I doing wrong? I am using jquery 3.

Comment: Library itself did this. If you want to change this you need to edit `jquery-3.2.1.min.js`

Comment: comment console.log('failed');

Comment: @M.Hemant failed is my control log to verify if fail method is called.

Comment: Are you using Chrome DevTools? It looks like the message is comming from DevTools itself. You could disable it using by turning "Hide network" option on. Though I don't see how this message is a problem :)

Comment: Don't shoot the messenger...fix the problem that causes them